# Limited size of FQL output

Tags: facebook-fql

I am trying to use FQL in order to get the number of comments of all posts on a Facebook page timeline.
I am executing :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20like_info.like_count%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id=%22130181453341%22&access_token=CAA...DED
```

However, this only displays the first posts of the timeline :

```
{ 
  "data": [ 
    { 
      "like_info": {
        "like_count": 0
      }      
    },
    ...      
    {
      "like_info": {            
        "like_count": 16         
      }      
    }   
  ]
}
```

The array stops at some point in the timeline. How to get the full timeline ?

Comment: Did you try appending a LIMIT attribute to your query?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention : I tried appending `&limit=200` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a where clause that specifies after what date you want comments.

Comment: `SELECT like_info.like_count FROM stream WHERE source_id="130181453341" AND created_time <= 1373852652` returns a new set of comments indeed. However, it's still a limited set of comments, I would like to get all comments instead of doing several requests.

Comment: By nature of how much stuff is in your stream it's unlikely you'll be able to get EVERYTHING you want. If I were you I'd also add in a limit to however many things you want back... But you should get comfortable with the results you're getting because I don't think there's an easy solution to get more.

Comment: Well the weird thing is that it's actually possible to get the number of likes of *all* posts, but it doesn't work for comments.